# Complex models in wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-7

I am looking for some wicket best practices tips.

I am refactoring a wicket app and I have a complex model. Meaning the object for the main model is a java bean that contains properties (and getters/setters) plus it contains other beans.

The main bean is 4 levels deep with other beans. This has simplified my code a lot because I can pass the top level bean into a component and it can change everything it needs. Little by little I have been populating the various beans with helper methods (e.g. exceedsMaximum(), isNull(), etc.).

Example:

```
public School {
    Person principal;
    List<Class> classList;
    public Student findStudent(String firstName, String lastName) { ... }
}
public Class {
    List<Students> studentList;
    Person teacher;
    String topic;
    public Float calculateClassGPA() { ... }
}
public Student {
    Float gpa;
    Person student;
    public Boolean isHonorStudent() { ... }
}
public Person {
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    Address address;
}
CompoundPropertyModel<School> schoolModel = new CompoundPropertyModel<School>(new School());
```

Is there any gotchas going down this path.  Should I be concerned about the overhead of passing the main model to a lot of components?  Would it be better to create a utility class for my helper methods to keep the beans pure?  Any red flags here?

Comment: I don't see any particular danger on your path :-). Just keep an eye on session size. A complex object graph could lead to a notable session size for your application.